# Implementing partition refinement algorithm

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, haskell, graph-algorithm

I have some nodes and edges

```
nodes = [
  { id: 'n1', propositions: ['p'] },
  { id: 'n2', propositions: ['p'] },
  { id: 'n3', propositions: ['p'] }
];
edges = [
  { source: 'n1', target: 'n2' },
  { source: 'n2', target: 'n1' },
  { source: 'n1', target: 'n3' },
  { source: 'n2', target: 'n3' }
];
```

As seen in the data, the two nodes `n1` and `n2` are pointing against each other, and both `n1` and `n2` are each pointing at `n3`.

I am trying to implement the algorithm on http://homepages.cwi.nl/~jve/courses/lai0506/LAI11.pdf#page=25 in JavaScript.

From what I understand, the initial partition will have only one block that contains all three nodes `n1`, `n2`, and `n3`. The second partition will have `n1` and `n2` in one subblock and `n3` in another subblock. The third partition will be the same as the second partition, so the iteration will halt. And as I have understood, all nodes in a subblock are redundant except of one, so I can just remove them and keep only one.

I have first created an initial partition Pi_0 by grouping the nodes with the same propositions. Then I move onto iterating until no changes are made since the last partition.

What I have come up with so far is

```
/**
 * Initial partition
 **/

// blocks in initial partition
const partition = {};

// group nodes into blocks based on propositions
nodes.forEach(function (node) {
  // use propositions as key
  const key = node.propositions.sort().join();

  // create block if it does not already exists
  if (!partition[key]) {
    partition[key] = [];
  }

  // add node to block
  partition[key].push(node);
});

/**
 * Iterate until P_{i} = P_{i - 1}
 **/

// repeat until Pi_{i} = Pi_{i-1}
while (true) {
  // get ready to partition each block in the partition into subblocks
  const newPartition = {};

  // go through each block in partition
  Object.keys(partition).forEach(function (blockName) {
    // get block by blockName
    const nodesInBlock = partition[blockName];

    // go through each node in the block
    nodesInBlock.forEach(function (sourceNode) {
        // ...
        // ...

        // create subblock if it doesn't already exists
        if (!newPartition[key]) {
          newPartition[key] = [];
        }

        // add node to subblock
        newPartition[key].push(sourceNode);
      });
    }
  });

  // if nothing changed
  if (Object.keys(partition).length === Object.keys(newPartition).length) {
    break;
  } else {
    partition = newPartition;
  }
}
}
```

But I don't know what to do instead of the snippet where I wrote `...`.

I guess I should get the name of the block to which the node points (i.e. the target node's block name), and then create a key from the source node's block name and the target node's block name. I just don't know how. From [page 27](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~jve/courses/lai0506/LAI11.pdf#page=27), the implementation is described in Haskell, but I don't understand Haskell, so it won't help me.

## Edit

I guess the partitions should look like this

```
// data:
nodes = [
  { id: 'n1', propositions: ['p'] },
  { id: 'n2', propositions: ['p'] },
  { id: 'n3', propositions: ['p'] }
];
edges = [
  { source: 'n1', target: 'n2' },
  { source: 'n2', target: 'n1' },
  { source: 'n1', target: 'n3' },
  { source: 'n2', target: 'n3' }
];

// initial partition
initialPartition = [
  { id: 'n1', propositions: ['p'] },
  { id: 'n2', propositions: ['p'] },
  { id: 'n3', propositions: ['p'] }
];

// second partition
secondPartition = [
  [
    { id: 'n1', propositions: ['p'] },
    { id: 'n2', propositions: ['p'] }
  ],
  { id: 'n3', propositions: ['p'] }
];

// third partition
thirdPartition = [
  [
    { id: 'n1', propositions: ['p'] },
    { id: 'n2', propositions: ['p'] }
  ],
  { id: 'n3', propositions: ['p'] }
];
```

So because the second and third are equal, the iteration process halts.

Comment: I guess that's Haskell You can mimic most part of it with ES6 syntax.

Comment: I just can't interpret it. I have read it tons of times and still don't understand it :D

Comment: which of them gives you problems? `nub` removes duplicates and keeps only one of each group of duplicates in a list; `and [condition | agent <- agents]` means the `condition` holds for each `agent` among `agents`; `bl part x = head [b | b <- part, elem x b]` returns first block in partition that contains `x`; and `rel2part (x:xs) r = ( x : [y | y <- xs, r x y] ) : rel2part [y | y <- xs, not (r x y)] r` partitions list into blocks of elements equivalent to each other according to a given relation `r`.

Comment: Maybe I also don't fully understand the algorithm. I have tried reading about it, but I can still not implement it

Comment: I didn't spend much time reading those slides, however I believe the algorithm proposed isn't as efficient. If I did not misunderstood the description they take a block `B`, for each node they compute all reachable agents and they partition `B` into subblocks `B1`, ..., `Bn` that reach the same sets of agents, and then repeat for the next block in the partition.  This is somewhat the reverse of what you usually do with partition refinement algorithms. You usually take a block `S`, compute the preimage of `S` and track the blocks `B1`,...,`Bn` that you reached. Every block `Bi` can be

Comment: split into two subsets: nodes of `Bi` that you have found in the preimage of `S`, and those that do not. Here comes the optimization that makes the algorithm O(nlogn): if `Bi`, as a whole, was already used as a splitter previously at this point you can choose one of the two subblocks and ignore it for further splitting operations, preserving correctness of the result. By ignoring the bigger of the two you always at least halve the size of the blocks -> nlog n instead of n^2.

Comment: (Obviously I have simplified a lot in the above comments, I just wanted to give the fundamental ideas since part of my thesis was developing partition refinement algorithms for Markov models of PEPA and implementing the algorithms into the PEPA Eclise plug-in).

Comment: Thank you! I am not quite sure how to compute the preimage of `S`, but I will read about it. Can you refer to any code snippets that implement the algorithm you just described?